# Cassandra NoSQL Database Types Supported

Tags: cassandra, nosql

What types of Nosql databases does Cassandra Nosql support?
These are the 4 main types:

1) Key Value Pair

2) Document Database

3) Column Store

4) Graph Based

[DBAstack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193086/cassandra-nosql-database-types-supported)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of useful information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra). If you are new to cassandra, I would recommend you to take a free [course](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling) for better understanding.

> Cassandra is essentially a hybrid between a key-value and a
>   column-oriented (or tabular) database management system. Its data
>   model is a partitioned row store with tunable consistency. Rows
>   are organized into tables; the first component of a table's primary
>   key is the partition key; within a partition, rows are clustered by
>   the remaining columns of the key. Other columns may be indexed
>   separately from the primary key

Comment: there is tip that leaving links in stackoverflow is not always best, become sometimes links can be extinct, so cassandra offers two hybrid,   does it offer document database or graphbased?

Comment: Cassandra is not document or graph-based nosql database